# Bounce Path using Parametric equations

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric

I have the serve of a tennis ball, mapped by  parametric equations $x(t)=31.389t$ and $y(t)=3.10-3t-4.9t^2$. I want the ball to bounce back after it hits the ground, $y=0$, just like a real tennis ball. How can I graph the bounce path of the tennis ball? The velocity and height loss by the ball needs to be close to real-life scenario although it isn't crucial.

[The graph of the serve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koPWT.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @YiFan well i havent tried much. I thought of doing some translation to get the function in the position I want, but I dont think it's logical.

Comment: Then you should try more, and then add your efforts into the question with an edit. People here don't generally receive "here's my homework, do it for me" type questions very well.

Comment: @YiFan Sorry, I didn't given enough context as it is hard to put in English. I don't really need it done for me. WiI just need hints like what type of terms can I google to lead me to a method of doing it?

Comment: @user101289295 the expectation is that you have shown efforts that you tried the question before showing it here. The reason is because showing your efforts allows both yourself and people looking to help you to understand where exactly you're stuck, and help you better. All you need to do is to try to do it, and explain where exactly you're stuck. Welcome to MSE!